# virtual printer to python

Tags: python, printing, virtual

I looking for advice, how to make this.  I need make virtual printer, and when I will sent any text file(word, excel, pdf) to this printer, I want, that my python script can get this data and parse it to variable. Just windows platform. Any idea?

Comment: Perhaps you need a printer driver

Comment: Alternatively just print it to PDF and convert it to an image and parse the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here I have printed this web page from Edge using Windows generic text printer

[image]

It was a stock method for extracting text to use the Generic/Text Only virtual printer since the days of pre windows. **The results are highly variable.**

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Having shown you it is possible. I will add that the results are often disappointing and frustrating to work with., for many reasons.

**Thus it is better to work with a Programable (API) replacement such as one that may OCR etc.**

For example try out one that formats text layout

[image]